# Coefficients in Functional Regression

Tags: r, pca, experiment-design, lm, functional-data-analysis

I would like to estimate the effect of DoE factors in my response which is a function.
For this reason, I tried to apply the Functional Data Analysis method.

As example,
I have a 12 treatment DoE,

```
library(dplyr)
library(mgcv) 
library(AlgDesign) 
library(reshape2) 
library(ggplot2) 

set.seed(123)



cand_list = expand.grid(
            x1 = c('Level_1', 'Level_2'),   x2 = c(0, 1.5, 3),   x3 = c(2, 7)) 

doe_grid <- optFederov( ~ x1 + x2 + x3, 
            data = cand_list, nTrials = 12, crit="D")$design
doe_grid$Run <- LETTERS[1:12]
```

and I measured the temperature/response through time at each treatment. Also, each response has different length which should be ok for FDA.

```
for(i in LETTERS[1:12]) {
  time_stamp <- 1:sample(9:12, 1)
  
  temp <- data.frame(
             Run = i, 
             Temperature = c(rnorm(1, 50, 4) - time_stamp*rnorm(1, 3, 1.5) + time_stamp^2*rnorm(1, .1, .03)),
             Time = 1 : length(time_stamp))
  ifelse(i == 'A', 
         results <- temp,
         results <- rbind(results, temp))
}


dat1 <- left_join(results, doe_grid, by = 'Run')
dat1 <- dat1 %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

find_max_Run <- dat1$Run %>% table %>% which.max
```

Then, I am fitting splines regression (`gam`) with `Temperature ~ Time` and I save the predictions/Functions

```
smooth_curves <- matrix(NA, nrow = dat1$Run%>% levels %>% length, ncol = 12) 
for(j in 1 : (dat1$Run %>% levels %>% length)){
  # j = 1
  fit <- gam(Temperature ~ s(Time,  bs = 'tp', k = 4), method = "REML", 
             subset = c(Run == unique(dat1$Run)[j]), 
             data = dat1)
  summary(fit)
  
  # plot(dat4$Time_id, dat4$Temperature)
  # lines(dat4$Time_id, fit$fitted)
  smooth_curves[j,] <- predict(fit, newdata = dat1 %>% 
       filter(Run == unique(dat1$Run)[find_max_Run])) # fit$fitted %>% length
}

smooth_curves %>% t %>% .[,1:3] %>%  matplot
```

Next, I am getting the eigenvectors (`fpca_loadings`) and scores (`fpca_scores`) for the first 2 FPCA,

```
fpca_res <- prcomp(smooth_curves, scale. = F, center = F)
fpca_scores <- fpca_res$x[,1:2]
fpca_loadings <- fpca_res$rotation[,1:2]
```

I fit linear model on each FPCA (using AIC to determine the "best" lm model).
Like `FPCA1 ~ DOE_factors`. Then using the linear models I am predicting the new scores (FPCA_new = `pred_scores`) for some new data (ok, here I don't really have new data but it doesn't matter).

```
lm_PC1 <- lm(fpca_scores[,1] ~ x1 * x2 * x3, data = doe_grid)

aic_PC1 <- MASS::stepAIC(lm_PC1, direction = "both", 
                      trace = F) 
summary(aic_PC1)

pred_PC1 <- predict(aic_PC1, newdata = doe_grid[1:3,])



lm_PC2 <- lm(fpca_scores[,2] ~ x1 * x2 * x3, data = doe_grid)

aic_PC2 <- MASS::stepAIC(lm_PC2, direction = "both", 
                      trace = F) 
summary(aic_PC2)

pred_PC2 <- predict(aic_PC2, newdata = doe_grid[1:3,])

pred_scores <- data.frame(pred_PC1, pred_PC2) %>% as.matrix
```

Finally, using the `fpca_loadings` from before and the new scores (`pred_scores`) I predict the functions.

```
mean_hat <- colMeans(smooth_curves)

pred_fun <- sweep(
  pred_scores %*% t(fpca_loadings[, 1:2]), 
  2, mean_hat, "+")
```

So far, so good (please comment otherwise).

I have the coefficients from `FPCA1 ~ DOE_factors` and `FPCA2 ~ DOE_factors` but I would like to have the coefficients for `Temperature ~ DOE_factors`.

Any ideas how to get the effect of DoE factors in Functional Regression?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have found the functional coefficients by multiplying the loadings with the coefficients from the two liner models (`lm_PC1` & `lm_PC2`).

```
lm_coef <- data.frame(coef(lm_PC1), coef(lm_PC2)) %>% as.matrix
pred_coef <- lm_coef %*% t(fpca_loadings[, 1:2])

pred_coef %>%  melt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = value, x = Var2, colour = Var1)) +
  geom_point()
```

Now, the coefficient here are functions as should be.

Also, some of the resources I used is [this1](http://www-stat.ucdavis.edu/%7Ewang/paper/jrsB65.pdf), [this2](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fbbd/571000a0368a2dd8552a4652286be60976bc.pdf), [this3](https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/%7Estaicu/FDAtutorial/module3-1.html) and, [this4](http://faculty.bscb.cornell.edu/%7Ehooker/FDA2008/) one (lecture 13).